# set iis web farm with WFF and ARR

Tags: iis, asp.net, web-hosting, web, web-farm

I use iis7 , wff, arr to setup a web farm.
On one web farm controller, the "ready for load balancing" of every content server turn yes almost immediately.

I use another machine to be the web farm controller, then  the "ready for load balancing" of every content server are all no (and I wait for a long time, say 8 hours).

The first machine is my developping machine, I've installed a bunch of software.
The second machine is my server, only iis7, wff, arr, .net 3.5,.net 4 is installed.
Is there any other software should be installed on the second machine to make the web farm controller to work right!
Any help, thanks!

Comment: Are the first web-farm controller and the web-farm located off-site and in a different IP net? if so, do you use a VPN or similar or how do you connect to the web-farm from your second machine?

Comment: Would VPN in that scenario slow things down?